# rails 3.2.3 - javascript - application.js - link_to_remove_fields

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails-3.2, link-to-function

I am trying to implement the idea of link_to_remove_fields from Ryan's "railscasts episode-197 ".

I seem to be having problems with the javascript file "

My application.html.erb file includes javascript:
    <%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>

And I add the following function to the application.js file:

```
function remove_fields(link) {
 $(link).previous("input[type=hidden]").value = "1";
 $(link).up(".fields").hide();
}
```

And I have the following code in the application_helper.rb file:

```
def link_to_remove_fields(name, f)
  f.hidden_field(:_destroy) + link_to_function(name, "remove_fields(this)")
end
```

And in my _form I have:

```
<%= f.label :entry, "Descriptions" %><br />
<%= f.text_area :entry, :rows => 3 %>
<%= link_to_remove_fields "remove", f %><br />
<%= f.hidden_field :user_id, :value => current_user.id %>
```

When i kick off the rails server and navigate to the page i am working on, the "remove" links appear, but nothing happens when I click on it.

So I have a hunch that the javascript code is not being called?

Any ideas?

Thanks guys!

Adam

Answer (score 1):

Can you please be sure, that your js code is not triggered? Please take a look with firebug or chromes build in debugtool